# @Id in hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have some code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

When I try to add user to table, I catch

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
insert into USER (id, birthday, email, first_name, last_name, login, password, id_role) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-181]
```

This is my code to add user to db

```
stock2.setBirthday(new Date(46));
stock2.setEmail("sss");
stock2.setFirstName("oleg");
stock2.setId(506l);
stock2.setLastName("gubov");
stock2.setLogin("OP");
stock2.setPassword("1");
Role role2 = new Role();
role2.setName("poil");
role2.setId(7l);
stock2.setRole(role2);

HibernateUserDao dao = new HibernateUserDao();
System.out.println(stock2.getId() + " -----------before");
dao.create(stock2);
```

and code of create method:

```
public void create(User user) {

    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

In my opinion, id is 7,but not NULL.
And "java" thinks otherwise. Where can be the problem?

Comment: First, I suppose your code block lacks the following line: `User stock2 = new User();`.

This would lead to the fact that the id you expect is 506 and not 7 (because of `stock2.setId(506l);`).

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `dao.create()`, so your intention is to insert row into database. Why are you using `GenerationType.IDENTITY` while inserting your own `id`?

`GenerationType.IDENTITY` means that your `JPA Provider` will make use of table's `IDENTITY` column (so, the `id` will be assigned at databse side). Hibernate, knowing that, will not send your `id` in an SQL statement.

By the way, it is not the best option for generating ids. `GenerationType.IDENTITY` has some performance problems (it does not support preallocation and `JPA Provider` may make `SELECT` query after each inserted row, just to know what the generated `id` was).

To be able to insert your own values as `id`s you can simply remove `@GeneratedValue` (which de facto means that you want `id`s to be generated automatically) annotation.

Answer (score 0):

User is a reserved keyword on most database engines, so change:

```
@Table(name = "USER")
```

to

```
@Table(name = "APP_USER")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link describing your issue and proposing possible solutions: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Common_Problems_4

Excerpt:

**null is inserted into the database, or error on insert.**

[...] It may also be that you did not set your primary key column in your table to be an identity type.